# how to add data in index column in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe where the first column is without any header. and I need to add 14 days to each value in that column. How can I do it?

```
                               L122.Y          5121.Y       110.Y  
2021-08-30 14:00:00             0.0             0.0       35.778441   
2021-08-30 15:00:00             0.0             0.0       35.741066   
2021-08-30 16:00:00             0.0             0.0       35.737846
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first column is called `index`, test it:

```
print (df.index)
```

If need convert it to `DatetimeIndex` and add days use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) + pd.Timedelta('14 days')
```

If already `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index += pd.Timedelta('14 days')
```